# How to make a chart using JSON downloaded from the REST API in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, data-visualization

Supposing I have a json file with a structure like this:

```
[
   {
      "time":"2014-06-29 21:02:08",
      "station":"s3",
      "data":{
         "wind_speed":"0.0",
         "softwaretype":"pywws",
         "wind_gust":"0.0",
         "temp":"22.2",
         "long":"unknown",
         "humidity":"59",
         "dewpoint":"13.8",
         "pressure":"1013.5",
         "datetimeutc":"2014-06-29 19:02:05",
         "wind_dir":"90",
         "lat":"unknown",
         "rain_1h":"0.0",
         "alt":"unknown",
         "rain_today":"0.0",
         "name":"1"
      }
   },
   {
      "time":"2014-06-29 21:02:56",
      "station":"s3",
      "data":{
         "wind_speed":"0.0",
         "softwaretype":"pywws",
         "wind_gust":"0.0",
         "temp":"22.2",
         "long":"unknown",
         "humidity":"59",
         "dewpoint":"13.8",
         "pressure":"1013.5",
         "datetimeutc":"2014-06-29 19:02:53",
         "wind_dir":"90",
         "lat":"unknown",
         "rain_1h":"0.0",
         "alt":"unknown",
         "rain_today":"0.0",
         "name":"1"
      }
   }
]
```

what's the easiest way to present the data visually, for example pressure/time chart (downloaded from the API) on a html webpage? I am not sure, but is this doable using only javascript and html?

Comment: the kind of visualisation is up to you, and yes you can totally make graphs out of that dataset with d3.js

Comment: @tomtomtom thanks for this information, however d3 looks like it has a very big entry barrier for someone with decent js skills

Comment: suppose i have data, someone build me a diagram ?, i use flot.js which  uses plot.js

Comment: @johnSmith I was looking for some advice on where to start, thaks for flot.js

Comment: use d3.js, or convert it into an svg on server side

Comment: well if you have some knowledge of how the DOM structure works -HTML and CSS, you can pretty much learn d3.js (that's what I did, so it kind of works)

Comment: thanks a lot, I just thought somewhere in the internet there'd be some simple solution / example.

Comment: What you want to do is look at how you want to present your data, then figure out how that presentation maps to what you can do with d3js. For example, you mentioned press/time chart - I'm assuming that would be a line graph. Go learn how to make a line graph with d3 and then apply what you've learned to your dataset.